# Error with super() when calling set_params() on sklearn estimators

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-3.4

I'm trying to load and configure scikit-learn estimators based on a config file. The file has the estimator class path and name as well as a dict of parameters. My plan was to load the estimator with its default parameters using pydoc.locate(), then call set_params() on the estimator using the dict of parameters. But I get the following error:

```
import pydoc
sgd = pydoc.locate('sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier')
print('{} {}'.format(type(sgd), sgd))
p_sgd = {'alpha':.1234}
sgd.set_params(p_sgd)
<class 'abc.ABCMeta'> <class 'sklearn.linear_model.stochastic_gradient.SGDClassifier'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/Users/doug/.pyenv/versions/learning-3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py", line 83, in set_params
    super(BaseSGD, self).set_params(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

I try to use this same "load and set" approach twice. The first time, I load a text vectorizer by name and set its parameters. The text vectorizer is a subclass I created based on HashingVectorizer. It does not produce this error, but also does not appear to be changed by the call to set_params() (i.e. the parameter values stay the defaults). The second time is the one for the classifier with the behavior I described.

I've used pydoc.locate() to load estimators previously when running them within a Pipeline provided to GridSearchCV. That worked fine. In that case, I construct the Pipeline using the default estimator constructors and then GridSearchCV has Pipeline make the calls to set_params() on each estimator while walking through the parameter grid. Looking through the Pipeline and GridSearchCV source, it looks like their use of set_params() is called as set_params(**param_dict). If I try that, I get a different error.

```
import pydoc
sgd = pydoc.locate('sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier')
p_sgd = {'alpha':.1234}
sgd.set_params(**p_sgd)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: set_params() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

One last note, I have read that the original error (TypeError: super(type, obj)...) has been traced to issues w/ loading a module multiple times. I do in fact use pydoc.locate() prior to these attempted calls (in order to trace their parentage and figure out who is a vectorizer vs classifier). I might be able to work around this, but there will still be prior attempts to load these modules since I am running in a loop to train multiple models based on the config file.

I'm using Python 3.4

Comment: `pydoc.locate` is giving you the SGDClassifier class, not an actual classifier. You are trying to use it as if it were a classifier.

Comment: Also, `pydoc.locate` isn't a public, documented API, and you shouldn't use it. You can just do `from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier`.

Comment: doh! I see. I fixed it by calling the returned class as a constructor. I had looked at that earlier, but had attempted it while passing the parameter dict to the constructor. But the estimator didn't have a kwargs option on its init so it failed for that reason. the below works.

import pydoc
sgd = pydoc.locate('sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier')()
p_sgd = {'alpha':.1234}
sgd.set_params(**p_sgd)
sgd
SGDClassifier(alpha=0.1234, average=False, class_weight=None, epsilon=0.1,
       eta0=0.0, fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15,...

Comment: I recognize that this is not the best way to load a class, but I can't do it explicitly in the code because I don't know which classifiers will be used. They are specified in an external and dynamic config file.

Answer (score 0):

As user2357112 pointed out, I was mistakenly only loading the class, not constructing it. I changed the code to call the constructor on the returned class with no arguments, then call set_params(**p_sgd) using the ** argument syntax I was expecting.

```
import pydoc
sgd = pydoc.locate('sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier')()
p_sgd = {'alpha':.1234}
sgd.set_params(**p_sgd)
sgd
SGDClassifier(alpha=0.1234, average=False, class_weight=None, epsilon=0.1, eta0=0.0, fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15, learning_rate='optimal', loss='hinge', n_iter=5, n_jobs=1, penalty='l2', power_t=0.5, random_state=None, shuffle=True, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```